# Connecting to USB in serial mode

Tags: usb, web

I have hardware which is connected to the mac or windows via USB Serial Mode. Currently, I have a nodejs application which sends and receive messages to this hardware using "serial" node module.
I am trying to connect to the hardware from WebPage. I used WebUSB serial.js. I am able to see the device and guess it is connecting. But when I try to send/receive the message - it says unable to claim the interface.

I would like to know can I use the WebUSB for usb with serial support?